# RSA Encryption - What property of RSA keys is causing the output after 5x RSA to be the same as the input?

Tags: rsa

For example,
R (R (R (R (R (m))))) = m where R(m) denotes the RSA encryption with public keys N and e.

What property of the RSA keys would cause this?

Comment: Note that this question suffers from the same issues, as the one you already asked: It doesn't clearly name the numeric values of $N$ and $e$ that yield the desired behavior. Also is there something in fgrieu's answer that left you unsatisfied?

Comment: Also please rather edit your old question than ask new ones that are essentially the same as the one that got closed w/o adressing the reason for closure.